# R - using `[[<-` and special assignment operations

Tags: r

When using the `dplyr`/`magrittr` packages, I've found that the `colnames<-` function can be extremely useful in a pipeline: (poor illustration of value, but solid illustration of functionality. A use case might be aggregating on an existing variable then modifying the name for a later join)

```
mydataframe %>% group_by(avar) %>% summarise(nrec = n(), mb = mean(bvar)) %>% 
`colnames<-`(c('avar2', 'nrec2', 'mb2'))
```

is equivalent to

```
mydataframe %>% group_by(avar) %>% summarise(nrec = n(), mb = mean(bvar))
colnames(mydataframe) <- c('avar2', 'nrec2', 'mb2')
```

I've learned that most sub-selection / attribute assignment operators can be rewritten in this way, but I'm struggling to see how this can be done. I tried something similar to

```
atestlist <- list('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
`[[<-`(atestlist, 4, value = 'val4')
```

And was hoping / expecting for something similar to

```
atestlist[[4]] <- 'val4'
```

But the first returns a new object which includes 'val4' where-as the second actually reassigns `atestlist` to contain a 4th value.

Why is it that (if I understand correctly) the same function called in different ways behaves differently? Trying to expand my R intuition a little further.

Comment: Not sure what your 2nd piece of code does and why it is equivalent with the 1st one. The 2nd one performs some grouping and summarising, but it changes the names of your original dataframe and not the one after your process. This will create a bug if your original dataframe has more than 3 columns. The 1st one prints the grouped and summarised dataframe with the names you selected, without saving/changing anything on your original dataframe.

Comment: Seems pretty likely that `[[<-` has to make a copy since your list is not large enough to begin with. If I try it with a list of appropriate length, no problem: `L = vector(4, mode="list"); \`[[<-\`(L, 4, "ha"); L`

Comment: Study the language definition: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Subset-assignment

Comment: You did not create the same expressions with `[[<-` and atestlist[[4]]<-. You can easily check that if you put deparse() around the respective code lines.

Comment: @r.user.05apr Nonetheless, the OP's second expression "works" if `length(atestlist) <- 4` is run first, so I guess there's more to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building complicated expressions like this, you could use the pryr::ast-function, which shows you the exact code structure of what you are doing. I think that you simply created 2 different expressions:

```
library(pryr)

# rm(list=ls())
ctestlist <- btestlist <- atestlist <- list('val1', 'val2', 'val3')

# mehtod 1
# --------
ast(atestlist[[4]] <- "val4")
# gives (spaces in console are important!): 
# > ast(atestlist[[4]] <- "val4")
# \- ()
# \- `<-
#   \- ()
# \- `[[
#   \- `atestlist
#   \-  4
# \-  "val4" 

atestlist[[4]] <- "val4"

# method 2
# --------
ast(`<-` (`[[`(btestlist, 4), value = "val4" ))
# > ast(`<-` (`[[`(btestlist, 4), value = "val4" ))
# \- ()
# \- `<-
#   \- ()
# \- `[[
#   \- `btestlist
#   \-  4
# \-  "val4"

`<-` (`[[`(btestlist, 4), value = "val4" ) # works like atestlist[[4]] <- "val4"

# this is slightly different:
# ---------------------------
ast(`[[<-`(ctestlist, 4, value = "val4"))
```

Comment: Your method 2 is not used by the OP, but rather the "slightly different" thing you mention at the end, right?

Comment: The 2nd method creates an expression that is the same as `atestlist[[4]]<- "val4"` . The slightly different way works too, when assigning twice ( `atestlist <- `[[<-`(atestlist, 4, value = "val4")` , (but then the function tree is different).